# Stereo Calibration and 3d Reconstruction

Tags: c#, opencv, computer-vision, emgucv, calibration

the result of 3d reprojection function is a matrix that has X,Y,Z of each pixel.

let's take the first element of this matrix points[0] which has: X= 414.580017 Y= -85.03029 Z= 10000.0

what is the unit here and where I can find this pixel in the image ? and why it is not like this X=0,Y=0,Z=10000.0!

```
points = PointCollection.ReprojectImageTo3D(disparityMap, Q);
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Could you elaborate what your problem is? What did you do to get the 3D re-projection matrix? 
How did you calibrate the stereo camera's?

Comment: output units are likely same as input units! of course we don't know what input units you used but i assume it's whatever the width / height of a pixel is.